# How can I fix jquery when i change table elements to div style in body section?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<body>   
 <input type="text" id="search"/>
    <table id="boxdata">
                <tr>
              <td class="namebox1">jQuery</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="namebox2">javascript</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td class="namebox3">php</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="namebox4">sql</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="namebox5">XML</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="namebox6">ASP</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</body>    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#search').keyup(function(){ 
        searchBox($(this).val());
       });
    });

    function searchBox(inputVal) {
    $('#boxdata').find('tr').each(function(index, row){
      var names = $(row).find('td');
      var found = false;
       if(names.length > 0) { 
         names.each(function(index, td) {
            var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
           if(regExp.test($(td).text()) & inputVal != ''){
              found = true;
                  return false;
           } 
           });
         if(found == true)
           $(row).addClass("red");
         else 
           $(row).removeClass("red");
        } 
      });
    }
    </script>
```

there's a textfield for searching words and there are 6 words in the each 6 boxes below textfield.(I omitted css codes. but, it wouldnt matter to solve the problem.). if i type a letter 's' then the words that including letter 's' like 'javascript', 'sql', 'ASP' these font-color will be changed black to red. And i made it by using table elements in html but i'd like to change all elements into div style to put some data fluidly later. i have difficulty to fix especially jquery. how can i fix it?

Comment: The question title doesn't match its content. Please re-word it or you'll start getting downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this a little bit.

```
function searchBox(inputVal) {
    
    var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
    
    $('#boxdata').find('tr').removeClass('red').filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('td').filter(function() {
           return regExp.test( $(this).text() );
        }).length && $.trim(inputVal).length;
    }).addClass('red');
    
}
```

So remove the `red` class from all `<tr>`'s first, then filter them, test the text of each `<td>`, if it matches, return the `<tr>` and then add the class `red` again.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C72XK/9/)

As for changing from a `table` to `div`, the jQuery would depend on how you structure your markup, but the principle would remain the same.

#### [Here's another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C72XK/12/)

Comment: i mean i wanna fix body section not table elements by using div tag and jquery. how can i fix it?

Comment: @MrSeo I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: i wanna change body section and jquery. By using div tag Not using table tag. would it be enough for you to understand?

Comment: @MrSeo did you read the last part of my answer, and look at the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can make javascript code HTML agnostic by using css classes instead of element names. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C72XK/36/).

```
function searchBox(inputVal) { 
    var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal = $.trim(inputVal), 'i'),
        highlight = 'red';

    $('#wrapper').find('.word') //instead of tr/td/div
                 .removeClass(highlight)
                 .each(function(){
                       var $this = $(this);
                       inputVal && regExp.test($this.text()) &&
                           $this.addClass(highlight);
                  });    
}
```